# How to "flatten" imported contracts

Tags: solidity, etherscan, brownie

I am trying to publish contracts on etherscan on an already deployed address. How would I "flatten" these imported files;

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

I tried

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.7.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol"
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/blob/main/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol"
```

And I get the error:

```
Source "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.7.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an add on extension on the Remix IDE where it does it for you automatically.

Check out: https://remix-project.org/

Comment: I went and dug up this video on flattening as I got fed up with trying to debug why javascript module wasn't working for me. Flattened my files out like pancakes. Thank you!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Z_VHCiMwiU

Answer (score 2):

If you are not going to use it from Remix I'd recommend this [solidity-flattener](https://github.com/poanetwork/solidity-flattener). Works pretty well for me. Very easy and flexible to use.

Comment: Cool, I ended up following this lad's tutorial on flattening files...

https://medium.com/coinmonks/flattening-your-solidity-files-702dec89f0bd

To which I'm finding other errors, which I'll open up another question for. But thank you for leading me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

In **Visual Studio Code** you can flatten smart contacts using [Solidity extension from Nomic Foundation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NomicFoundation.hardhat-solidity) by right-click on the file you want to flatten and choosing **Hardhat: Flatten this file and its dependencies** option. It works pretty well with all imported contracts and dependencies.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Remix , then you have an option to flatten your contract . Just right click on the smart contract file and you can see the option to flatten your contract .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you develop with truffle you can use [truffle-plugin-verify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-plugin-verify) to verify a smart contract with a single command in the console without have to flatten any file.